# validates uniqueness of a column with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on a model which has a status column(active or deleted)

Right now, I have a validation for uniqueness like this

```
validates :name, :uniqueness => {:scope => :user_id }
```

I would like to add another 'scope' for ACTIVE records only. Somewhat like the validation below(which did not work)

```
validates :name, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id }, condition: ['state = ?', 'active']
```

If I'll do my validation in SQL Statement, it will be 'something' like below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE name = '[name]' AND status = 'active'
```

One solution for  this problem is adding a default scope but not in my case, I don't need to have a default scope.

Answer (score 0):

If the model running the validation is `active`, then you could just add `state` as another scope:

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: [:user_id, :state] }
```

Keep in mind that a model with `active` state will check for uniqueness against other `active`, but a `deleted` one will check against other `deleted`.

Answer (score 0):

in your model you can do

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :field_name, :scope => :second_field_name, :message => 'error_message' , :condition => ['state = ?', 'active']
```